# How can I get the Cache Driver ? (Symfony2 with Doctrine/Redis Cache)

Tags: symfony, caching, orm, redis, doctrine

For use **Redis Cache** in my **Symfony2** Application, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.maxpou.fr/cache-doctrine-avec-redis/) (in French, sorry!).

Everything well except the part I use **Entity Listeners** from **Doctrine** Events for updating my Cache when Database writing... I have a Service like that :

```
<?php

namespace Maxpou\BeerBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Maxpou\BeerBundle\Entity\Beer;

class BeerListener
{
    private $cacheDriver;

    public function __construct($cacheDriver)
    {
        $this->cacheDriver = $cacheDriver;
    }

    public function postPersist(Beer $beer, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->cacheDriver->expire('[beers_all][1]', 0);
    }

    public function postUpdate(Beer $beer, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->cacheDriver->expire('[beers_all][1]', 0);
    }

    public function postRemove(Beer $beer, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->cacheDriver->expire('[beers_all][1]', 0);
    }
}
```

And in my config.yml I add :

```
beer_listener:
    class: Maxpou\BeerBundle\Service\BeerListener
    arguments:
        - "@snc_redis.doctrine"
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

And in my Entity I add the following annotation :

```
* @ORM\EntityListeners({"Maxpou\BeerBundle\Service\BeerListener"})
```

When I try to do an update, I have the following errors :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Maxpou\BeerBundle\Service\BeerListener::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/admin2/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/DefaultEntityListenerResolver.php on line 73 and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/admin2/src/Maxpou/BeerBundle/Service/BeerListener.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/admin2/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/DefaultEntityListenerResolver.php(73): Maxpou\BeerBundle\Service\BeerListener->__construct()
#1 /var/www/admin2/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Event/ListenersInvoker.php(110): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultEntityListenerResolver->resolve('Maxpou\\BeerBundle\\...')
#2 /var/www/admin2/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(1075): Doctrine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker->invoke(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), 'postUpdate', Object(Maxpou\BeerBundle\Entity\Beer), Object(Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs), 3)
#3 /var/www/admin2/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(384): Doctrine\ORM\Unit in /var/www/admin2/src/Maxpou/BeerBundle/Service/BeerListener.php on line 12
```

It seems, I don't get the **$cacheDriver** param in my BeerListener

Someone would have an idea of why?

**PS:** I use "symfony/symfony": "~2.5.0", "doctrine/orm": "~2.2", "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2", "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "~1.0", "snc/redis-bundle": "1.1.x", "predis/predis": "^1.0" (in NGINX/PHP-7.1 env)